# Express Route Testing - req.parameter

Tags: express, jestjs

How would one test an express route such as `app.get('/myapp/:parameter')`

How would I use jest to test that no parameter was passed? I have an error that will return a 400 if not passed in my `.ts` file but having no luck in my test as seen below:

```
await supertest(app).get(‘/app/myapp/‘).then((res) => { expect(res.status).toEqual(400) })
```

This test won’t even hit my file, gets hung up and a 'timeout error' happens

My await and a sync are all set up properly have similar tests but with the other routes they're `/myapp/parameter?=…`

These tests all pass

Answer (score -1):

If it gets hung up then you need to tell the test case explicitly when it is done.
You can get `done` function from the callback param and call it when you assert values.

```js
test('my-test', (done) => {
  someAsyncFn().then(() => {
    expect(1+1).toBe(2);
    done();
  })
});
```

You can try this approach too

```js
supertest(app)
 .get('/app/myapp/')
 .expect(400)
 .end(function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
```

More examples [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#callbacks)